# cordova windows universal app build failed in visual studio 2015

Tags: windows, cordova, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

i am developing cordova windows universal app.i am Successfully associated app with the Store and  trying to build the app getting theses errors

Please suggest me to fix build errors

[Please find Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsdrU.png)

Comment: did you try to remove and add platform again? Surprisingly, that action solved some of my cordova app build problems.

Comment: Hi Ognjen Babic,Thanks for replay.I am tried still same error

Comment: did you try to build it with cordova ? Open cmd and navigate to location of the project and type cordova build windows --archs=x86

Comment: Yes Ognjen Babic, Same Error in cmd also

Comment: Did you get this error before associating with the store? Could you please offer a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi Elvis Xia,Thanks for replay.After Associating Store.